# Aptana Studio Apache Tomcat support

Tags: apache, tomcat, aptana3

Really frustrated with IDE, I simply need basic js editor with suggestion support when you make method call with '.' + 'space'. So if I add jQuery I can view the available methods. Installed aptana studio, but it comes with no servers pre-installed at all. I cannot call it professional product, since this is incompetency. On top of that adding server is haemorrhoidal procedure, nothing like we do it in STS or Eclipse.

I am seeking for simple tutorial on how to register the apache tomcat server on aptana studio. I don't want to write start/stop commands or know what 'document root' jargon means. I don't want to install additional server named 'wamp' just to use it with aptana studio. And I don't want to install aptana studio as a plugin since it breaks the fonts and background colours for all other files in STS and it crashes a lot.

**If it is easy to do and I am just hot-headed then please accept my apologies and offer me a guide, but if it is pain in the fifth place I would rather follow your recommendations for using other really good JavaScript editors/IDE.**

Open-source lack of standards is really becoming something I can call specific non-transferable knowledge which has no value at all, so I obviously has no intention of learning the complicated internal guts of AS.

Thank You,

Answer (score 0):

Add su "tomcatuser" pwd:"tomcatuserpassword" to the server start command, startup.sh on linux startup.bat on other OS. Do this using the edit server option in aptana under the show view -> server option.